# How to get frame timestamp when MediaCodec decoder is configured with SurfaceTexture output?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I have an Android MediaCodec decoder configured with a Surface from a SurfaceTexture object. MP4 file decoding works fine, the frames can be seen on the device. But if try to re-encode to a new MP4 file with MediaMuxer, the output file size is zero, because SurfaceTexture.getTimestamp() returns always 0. What is the proper way to get frame presentation time in this case?

Comment: Thanks fadden, I was hoping you are around!

Answer (score 1):

Time stamps are forwarded.  The time stamp you get from SurfaceTexture is whatever was provided by the producer.

When decoding with MediaCodec, you receive the timestamp in a BufferInfo object.  You either pass that timestamp to the encoder's `queueInputBuffer()` directly, or if you're rendering with GLES you pass it to `eglPresentationTimeANDROID()`, which makes it available to the SurfaceTexture.

One example can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/InputSurface.java#167), others in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: Just to clarify, does the observed sequence look like this:
* eglPresentationTimeANDROID( frameTime )
* SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage()
* SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener.onFrameAvailable()
* SurfaceTexture.getTimestamp() returns frameTime